# Caching of web pages and SPA

Tags: html, single-page-application, browser-cache, http-caching

I have read about SPA (single page application) and learned that biggest advantage of those is that save network traffic because SPA downloads all (at least most of them) application resources when loading the page.

But I am not clear on this - suppose in my `index.jsp` I have specified all my resources and downloaded when loading `index.jsp`. Now my application navigation starts from `index.jsp`, so for navigation I submit my form and which has `action="user.jsp"`

Now, since I have `action="user.jsp"` so on submitting the form my web browser will send a request to server to get `user.jsp`. **Please correct me if I am wrong.** Or will be taken from HTTP cache. But lets say through some Apache setting (I have read somewhere that it is possible but don't know how to do it) I have disabled the HTTP caching of web page then `user.jsp` will be downloaded from server.

Much appreciated if somebody can throw good insight on it. Basically I am confused with the fact that `action="user.jsp"` will lead a call to server and HTTP/browser can cache web pages.

*P.S.: I accidentaly posted my question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1051999/caching-of-web-pages-and-spa) as a guest user but now unable to remove that, so if you have moderation authorities then please get that question remove to avoid duplication.*

Comment: A Single Page Application tends to do all its interactions through Javascript (via AJAX), not through loading the page anew. So in a SPA, your form wouldn't really have a meaningful `action`, but it would be sent using JavaScript. Given that Ajaxy pages make a truckload of requests, just saving a bit of traffic is unlikely to be worth the effort of switching to SPAs though, it should also make sense from other points of view.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ok, but a web app will need different resources like HTML/JSP, CSS, JS, JSON etc. to download, right? So, SPA will download all this for the first time when the launch page is downloaded,and then to render different view or web page or functionality there is no need to go to server because resource is already downloaded. At least this is my understanding and now I am more confused. I agree on that to get some dynamic data it can make AJAX call to server and refresh the content of page. But to go to all together a different screen it will need its HTML/JSP, right?

Comment: And whether it will load that HTML/JSP from HTTP cache or get it from server?

Comment: A Single Page Application is an application where everything stays within one document, without reloading it. If you reload the page it's not a SPA. Yes, any big change on the page will have to be loaded somehow, be it as a new page, or through Ajax. A SPA loads entire pages through Ajax.